# std::array incomplete type error with an array of std::tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, glm-math

I am getting some strange behaviour with a C++11 `std::array`. When I try to compile with `std::array<std::tuple<int, float>, 6> myTuples;` as a member variable, I get these errors:

`mingw32\4.7.2\include\c++\array:-1: In instantiation of 'struct std::array<std::tuple<int, float>, 6u>':`
`mingw32\4.7.2\include\c++\array:77: error: 'std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::_M_instance' has incomplete type`

I'm not sure if any of this changes anything but the class it is in is a template class derived from another template class. The template parameter is an `unsigned int` an determines the size of a protected `std::array` in the base class, which I reference in the derived class `using Base<param>::m_array;`. The derived class has various `glm::vec3/dmat4/quat` types, and uses OpenGL fixed function `glBegin(GL_QUADS);` stuff. I'm using SDL-1.2.15 to create an OpenGL context. I think most of that was irrelevant, but maybe not. I could paste code, but everything is interconnected, so it can only be compiled as a whole (which distributed between sources is around a thousand or so lines).

However, when I include this same line in [this ideone example](http://ideone.com/O7TCMe), in very similar circumstances, it compiles perfectly fine. I checked that it wasn't just my compiler (MinGW g++ version 4.7.2) by compiling the same on my compiler with command line `g++ -Wall -std=c++11`

Does anyone know why I might get these errors? I had some problems before with the compiler crashing while parsing `std::array` assignment (using `array = {{a,b,c}};` for a default parameter), but this time its a compiler error not crash.

Comment: Have you done `#include <array>`?

Comment: I can reproduce a similar error if you forget to include `<tuple>`. Actually, the same exact error with g++4.7 `/usr/include/c++/4.7/array:77:43: error: ‘std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::_M_instance’ has incomplete type`

Comment: Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: "*I checked that it wasn't just my compiler [...] by compiling the same on my compiler*" Using the same compiler *twice* is *not* how you check for compiler errors.

Comment: @NicolBolas What I meant was that I thought maybe it was just my compiler that had issues, so I simplified the problem and then compiled on ideone's compiler (which I think is GCC 4.8). This worked so I then suspected that my compiler might have a bug. Testing with my original compiler revealed that the error on the single line was not a compiler bug.

Comment: @JesseGood Yep, that's the problem. Well diagnosed. Could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As per requested, you forgot to include `<tuple>` which is why the compiler complained of an incomplete type.

Comment: In my case I forgot to add `#include <array>`